# WPF DataGrid Editing Difficulty (InvalidOperationException)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection, invalidoperationexception

I have a `DataGrid` that I am filling with information from an `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<T>>` where T is an object of mine that implements `IEditableObject`.

I have the `DataGrid`  correctly filling with the information I need.  The problem is that when I go to edit a box in it I get an exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view
```

followed by the subsequent stack trace.

I understand binding as well as the idea that in an `ObservableCollection<T>` if you want to be able to edit the `DataGrid` items than you need to implement the `IEditableObject` interface in the object `T`.

I'm not sure why it won't let me edit, although I'm leaning more towards the idea that I need to attach my object to some type of view.

I've not found much on what I'm trying to do but I have been fairly successful up until this point in getting over hurdles.  If anyone has any insight as to what I should do it is much appreciated.

Also, I will post code if someone would seriously like to see it but I believe it's less about what I've already written and more about what I still need to write.

Edit: Added code

```
private void dg_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        grid.Columns.Clear();
        TableNode node = e.NewValue as TableNode;
        if (node != null)
        {
            InfoTable dti = new InfoTable(m_model.EditNode.Database.Path, node.FullName);
            int index = 0;
            foreach (string colName in dti.Columns)
            {
                DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
                col.Header = colName;
                col.Binding = new Binding("[" + index + "].Info");
                //Note: .Info is the information string in the class T containing the data that may or may not be edited
                grid.Columns.Add(col);
                index++;
            }
            grid.ItemsSource = dti;
        }
    }
```

Here I am binding the columns to each `ObservableCollection` in the `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollections<T>>` that is in my `InfoTable`.  I have implemented `IEnumerable` and `INotfiyPropertyChange` in the `InfoTable`.

Comment: Post the code. It will help!

Comment: So each row in your DataGrid contains an ObservableCollection? Have you tried setting `SelectionUnit="Cell"` (just guessing, to be honest)?

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 Added the code!

Comment: @almulo Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your `InfoTable` class needs to implement `IList`, too, in order to support DataGrid editing.

`IList` adds the capability of adding and removing items, and the DataGrid probably needs that to manage its rows.

Comment: Thank you! It works, now if I can't just get the changes to save....Welp that'll be for another question if I can't figure it out